# How to Auto-Refresh in React After Logic Check

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm running a Rails application and using React for the views.  In my main component, I'm checking to see if a Rails object is empty.  If it's empty, I'm displaying one component, if the object isn't empty, I'm displaying another.

```
if (this.props.projects.length > 0){
        var projectList = <Project_list projects={this.state.projects} /> }
    else {
        var projectList = <Noproject />
    }
```

This works fine, but once I create that first new project and it's added to the object, I have to refresh the page the very first time to get the other component to load.  After that, my React logic adds objects to the displayed list dynamically without ever having to refresh.

Here's the main component file:

```
class Projects extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        projects: this.props.projects,
        project_name: '',
        project_zipcode: '',
        project_timeframe: '',
        project_supplier: '',
        showModal: false
    }
}


openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ 
        showModal: true 
    });
}

closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
        showModal: false,
        project_name: '',
        project_zipcode: '',
        project_timeframe: '',
        project_supplier: ''
    });
}

handleUserInput(obj) {
    this.setState(obj);
}

handleFormSubmit() {
    const project = {
        name: this.state.project_name, 
        zipcode: this.state.project_zipcode, 
        timeframe: this.state.project_timeframe,        
        supplier: this.state.project_supplier
    };
    $.post('/projects',
        {project: project})
        .done((data) => {
            this.addNewProject(data);
        });
    this.setState({
        showModal: false
    })
}

addNewProject(project){
    const projects = update(this.state.projects, { $push: [project]});
    this.setState({
        projects: projects.sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date(b['updated_at']) - new Date(a['updated_at']);
        })
    });
    this.setState({
        project_name: '',
        project_zipcode: '',
        project_timeframe: '',
        project_supplier: ''
    })
}

render() {

    if (this.props.projects.length > 0){
        var projectList = <Project_list projects={this.state.projects} /> }
    else {
        var projectList = <Noproject />
    }

    return (

        <div>
           <h2>Start a New Project</h2>
                <Button
                    bsStyle="success"
                    bsSize="large"
                    onClick={this.openModal} >
                    Create a New Project
                </Button>

                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.closeModal}>
                  <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Create a New Project</Modal.Title>
                  </Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Body>

                    <Project_form 
                    project_name={this.state.project_name} 
                    project_zipcode={this.state.project_zipcode} 
                    project_timeframe={this.state.project_timeframe}
                    project_supplier={this.state.project_supplier}
                    onUserInput={(obj) => this.handleUserInput(obj)}
                    onFormSubmit={() => this.handleFormSubmit()} />

                  </Modal.Body>
                  <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.closeModal}>Cancel</Button>
                  </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>



                <div className="col-md-12">                     
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      {projectList}
                    </div>                              
                </div>                  
        </div>

        )
}
}

const destination = document.querySelector(".projects")

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 const node = document.getElementById('projects_data')
 const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data'))
 ReactDOM.render(
<Projects projects={data} />,
destination)

})
```

How would you perform this logic check so you don't need to refresh the page or is there a different way to auto load the other component without a page refresh?

Comment: Just a side note on your component naming conventions. Components in react are usually named in PascalCase. So I would call them ProjectList and NoProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question needs a bit more details.. What is that `update` method? Is it a call to the server? What does it return? Also, what is the second `setState` used for? Why not perform all `setState` in one call?

Is projects coming from state of from props? If it is maintained in state, you can change `this.props.projects` to `this.state.projects` and then your component will update once state changes.

You can initialize `this.state.projects` with your Rails data in `componentWillMount` or something like that..

If you share a bit more code i'll be able to help you better

Comment: I added the main component file if that helps.

Comment: Does addNewProject actually update this.props.projects? Why not use this.state.projects in the condition of your render method?

Comment: How can I use this.state.projects in the render method?  Was wondering if there was an easier way to load the component when addNewProject is called without making this.props.project a stateful element...

Comment: To use ```this.state.projects``` in render method you can just write ```this.state.projects``` instead of ```this.props.projects``` :-) I see you're initializing this.state.projects in the constructor so it should be identical to this.props.projects at least on first render. 

Another option is to move the NoProjects logic inside ProjectList. Then, your Projects component will be a 'container' component and the ProjectList will render either a project list if there are projects, or a NoProjects component if there are no projects.

Comment: I changed:  this.props.projects to this.state.projects in the render method and it worked great!  Thanks, @Uri-klar